# Creating new SLES 12 VM on XenServer 6.5 fails

Tags: virtual-machine, xen, sles

When I try to create a new SLES 12 VM on a XenServer 6.5 host it fails with this error message:

```
"Failed","Starting VM 'AAEB-PUBLIC218LY' Internal error: xenopsd internal error: 
       VM = 4d956449-7325-0793-5a0c-63f0f10c31c7; domid = 18;
          Bootloader.Bad_error Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/bin/eliloader", line 1153, in ?
    sys.exit(main())   File "/usr/bin/eliloader", line 1143, 
    in main handle_first_boot(vm, img, args, other_config)   
          File "/usr/bin/eliloader", line 870, in handle_first_boot
    kernel, ramdisk = sles_first_boot_handler(vm, repo_url, other_config) 
          File "/usr/bin/eliloader", line 677, in sles_first_boot_handler
    fetchFile(vmlinuz_url, vmlinuz_file, pv_kernel_max_size)   
          File "/usr/bin/eliloader", line 316, in fetchFile
    raise ResourceNotFound, source
    __main__.ResourceNotFound
```

All articles I found in net do not apply to this problem.

Any idea what is going  wrong?

**Notes:**

1. I am using the XenServer SLES 12 64bit template.
2. The VM has 3072 MB RAM.
3. The VM has 15 GB hard disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the XenServer loader I realized what the problem was: I added by mistake the wrong ISO file as the boot device.

To be more specific:
I added `SLE-12-SDK-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso` instead of `SLE-12-SP1-Server-DVD-x86_64-GM-DVD1.iso`. Yes, I know, a stupid mistake....